# Append elements with different attributes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to add buttons to a div with the append Method using D3. Each added button should have a different onclick-attribute.

```js
var row = 0;

function addButton () {
  row++
  d3.select("div")
    .append("button")
    .text("Add Node - Row " + row)
    .attr("onclick", "addNode(row)");
}

function addNode(row) {
  window.alert(row);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>


<button onclick="addButton()">Add Button</button>
<div></div>
```

When I run the function 'addButton' it correctly adds a button to the the div. However when I add a second button by running the function one more time the attribute of the first button gets overwritten, so that both buttons now have the the same onclick-attribute. Oddly enough it works for ".text" but not for ".attr".
What do I have to do to not effect the previous added buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for text since you actually use the value of the `row` variable. Simply do the same thing as you've done in your call to `text()` and it will work as expected (note `addNode(${row})`):

```js
var row = 0;

function addButton () {
  row++
  d3.select("div")
    .append("button")
    .text("Add Node - Row " + row)
    .attr("onclick", `addNode(${row})`);
}

function addNode(row) {
  window.alert(row);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>


<button onclick="addButton()">Add Button</button>
<div></div>
```